# Installation problems

Tags: system-installation

I passed elementary OS into a 128gb flash as instructed. However, when I boot from the flash, I can't install the elementary OS. Most times I see the e logo and then a black screen with no windows or bars, only the mouse pointer.

What should I do?

Comment: Wonder whether I worth the "Tumbleweed" badge or if elementary os community does.